# fread error? invalid file identifier

Tags: excel, matlab

while executing, I have this error ?? Error using ==> fread
Invalid file identifier.  Use fopen to generate a valid file identifier. fid is equal to -1 but the file does exist.
what shall I do?

```
seq=dir('C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\Desktop\pfe\code final version 1\nor\info');
N=[];
for i = 3 : length(seq)
disp(seq(i).name)
cd 'C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\Desktop\pfe\code final version 1\nor\info'
fin = fopen('seq(i).name','r');
[x,count]=fread(fin,'char=>char');
cd 'C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\Desktop\pfe\code final version 1'
M=fichier(fin,x);
N=[N;M];
end
xlswrite('info.xls',N);
```

Answer (score 1):

As you put `''` around the name, you are trying to open a file called `seq(i).name`, remove the `''` and you are using the variable named `seq(i).name`

```
fin = fopen(seq(i).name,'r');
```